# Are there $x,y \in E$ such as $(x-y) \in \mathbb{I}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory

$E$ - measurable set and $|E| > 0$. Are there any $x,y \in E$ such as $(x-y) \in \mathbb{I}$

My answer is YES, but I don't know how to prove it.
Can someone give me a hint or show how to prove it?

Comment: $\mathbb I$ means the irrationals?  If so, then choose $x_0\in E$ and note that if $x-x_0\in \mathbb Q$ for every $x\in E$ then $E $ is countable (or finite).

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{I}$ means the irrationals

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what conclusion follows from the fact that E is finite

Comment: Or countable.  What is the measure of a set that is finite or countable?

Comment: I should say:  your post is very terse.  I am guessing that you are referring to the standard Lebesgue measure on the real line.  Of course there are different measures and there are some measures for which the desired claim is not true.

Comment: Yes, this is my mistake. I mean Lebesgues measure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose otherwise that $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $x,y\in E$. Then the set $\{x-y:x,y\in E\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, thus of measure zero. But, since $m(E)>0$, [Steinhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem) asserts us that there is $\delta>0$ such that $(-\delta,\delta)\subset \{x-y:x,y\in E\}$, thus this set has measure at least $2\delta>0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

A second answer, without the use of Steinhaus theorem (which is a strong result). Suppose that for all $x,y\in E$ it is $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$. Fix $x_0\in E$. Then we have that $y-x_0\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $y\in E$. But then $\{y-x_0:y\in E\}=E-x_0$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, so it is of measure zero. Since Lebesgue measure is invariant under translation,  it is $m(E-x_0)=m(E)$, thus $m(E)=0$, a contradiction.